# Send email from group email address

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am searching for an option to send an email from an Office 365 Group via Microsoft Graph.

I mean to send an email to another email address like `test@yahoo.com`.The group member can send email from this Group, but how can I get access via the API?

I can't find anything in the documentation for [Groups](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/group) or [Users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users).

Answer (score 4):

A `Group` doesn't have a mailbox in the same way as a `User` might. Instead of traditional emails, Groups use [Conversations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/conversation). A Conversation may contain multiple [threads](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/conversationthread) which are made up of one or more [posts](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/post).

Members of a Group may receive these conversations as an email, but only if they are [subscribed to conversations](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_subscribebymail) from that Group. If a given member isn't subscribed, they'll only see the conversations when accessing that Group directly.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'm a litte bit confused because I can send an email from a group to an person outside the group [Tutorial](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2016/02/18/office-365-group-sending-email-on-behalf-of-group-address/)

Comment: I've not tested this yet but assuming you've configured the SendAs permissions described in the article, you may be able to to use the [Setting the from and sender properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/message) feature of a `message` to acomplish this. Basically this allows you to change the `from` field to another email address you have permission to send on-behalf-of.